# ASP.NET - JQuery BootstrapValidator

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web form that has textbox (txtemail1, txtFName, txtPhone). I am using the Bootstrap validator. My issue is that when I test and leave the first name field null, every control on the form is highlighted as an error instead of just the txtFName control. How do I get only the control that is missing data to be flagged. For example, if a name is not entered, the first name displays the error message but all of the controls are highlighted as an error.

Here is my textbox markup:

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox> </td>
```

My JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form1').bootstrapValidator({
            container: '#messages',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                txtFName: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'First name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                txtEmail1: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email address is required'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'The email address is not valid'
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If one or 2 inputs empty out of 10, the error only will show to empty inputs, not on all of 10 inputs, I don't understand what you are trying to ask?

Comment: For example, If the firstname, email and phone are not filled in, only the firstname and email should be highlighted as a required field - not phone. Firstname and email are the only ones I have set up in the javascript to validate.

Comment: can  you paste the html rendered by asp and asp code used to generate html?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the callback function in order to get the field validated.

```
fields: {
                txtFName: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'First name is required'
                        },
                        callback: {
                            message: 'First name is required',
                            callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
// validate the input
 return value != "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Source : http://formvalidation.io/validators/callback/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting error message on input which you don't want to validate using `bootstrapValidator` is that the input has `required` condition, in your case as you mentioned in comment `phone input`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenubmer" value="" required >
```

[Fiddle with required condition](http://jsfiddle.net/js70ooy0/8/)

So should be

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenubmer" value="">
```

[Fiddle with no required condition](http://jsfiddle.net/js70ooy0/7/)

Comment: I am using asp.net server controls. My phone number textbox control does not have the required validator.

Comment: can you post your phone number input here

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPNumber" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Thanks for all the info, btw

Comment: Try with, add `CausesValidation="False"` to from submit button and see if it makes any difference